# '\n' not working in officegen module tables of node.js

Tags: node.js

Hi, I am using officegen to create .docx file in node.js.I need to shift to a new line in one of the table cells. However '\n' is not working for some reason

```
table[12] = ['Testing Tools used',retrieveelement(tempsoftware)+',\n '+retrieveelement(tempothertestcasemanagement)+', \n'+retrieveelement(tempautomation)+', \n'+retrieveelement(tempdefecttracking)+', \n'+retrieveelement(tempothertestingtool)]
```

The output just ignores '\n' and does mpthing. Can anyone suggest me what's wrong with my code. please note that retrieveelement() returns string(might be empty)

Answer (score 1):

use "\r\n".

Or you can provide lines within a cell in an array:

```
table[12] = ['Testing Tools used',[retrieveelement(tempsoftware),retrieveelement(tempothertestcasemanagement),retrieveelement(tempautomation),retrieveelement(tempdefecttracking),retrieveelement(tempothertestingtool)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some commas in the wrong places, and use double quotes for "\n":

```
table[12] = ['Testing Tools used', retrieveelement(tempsoftware) + ',' + "\n" + retrieveelement(tempothertestcasemanagement) + ',' + "\n" + retrieveelement(tempautomation) + ',' + "\n" + retrieveelement(tempdefecttracking) + ',' + "\n" + retrieveelement(tempothertestingtool)]
```